# iPhone - Web Access Authentication

Tags: iphone, authentication, passwords, uniqueidentifier

I am building a secure app for our exec's... here is my setup. It's a somewhat Macgyver approach, but bear with me :)

1. There are only 10 users, I have a record of each uniqueIdentifier on my backend in a database table. (This is internal only for our users, so I don't believe I am breaking the public user registration rule mentioned in the API docs)
2. Through adhoc distribution I install my app on all 10 devices
3. My app is simply composed of a UIWebView.
4. When the app starts it does a POST to our https site sending the uniqueIdentifier. (Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142562/loading-a-webpage-through-uiwebview-with-post-parameters))
5. The server page that recieves the POST, checks the uniqueIdentifier and if found sets a session cookie that automatically logs them into the site.
6. This way the user doesn't have to enter in their credentials every time.

So what do you think, is there a security hole with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you are storing all your unique IDs in the application, each of which is a credential that unlocks access, all I need to do is steal one of your employee's phones or otherwise get a copy of the application to look for those keys.

If you need to store credentials on the phone, use the [iPhone's Keychain](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html).

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'll check out the KeyChain doc. Yeah, I had thought about if their phones were stolen. Most users have it setup to ask for their passcode every 4 hours. On your second point: I could store the md5 version of their uniqueIdentifier

Comment: You might want to talk to a web app and/or iPhone security specialist, because what you're doing sounds a bit sketchy, to me. For example, md5crack would be one way to recover keys: http://md5crack.com/ Although the work you want to do may depend on how secure your application needs to be.