# Safari/OSX Webview changing request type

Tags: objective-c, angularjs, macos, webview

We are making an OSX version of our Windows app that relies heavily on webviews and some javascript API's.

In Windows, the basic flow is as follow:

1. The Application opens up  a webview
2. The Application loads a page in the webview that corresponds to our javascript api
3. The API (written in Angular) requests data from the application
4. The Application returns it
5. The API forms a JSON object
6. The API POST's the JSON object to a routing server (while loaded in the webview)
7. The routing server responds with an object (either an error or a JSON object containing the content URL to load
8. The API tells the application to load the new URL
9. The Application loads the new URL

On windows this works fine. On our OSX app, we can get to step 6. At this point, for some reason we can't figure out, the request type is being changed. Whereas it should be a POST, instead it is showing up as a GET. The routing server returns an error at this point since it expect the POST (and consequently, the POST data)

Since this problem doesn't happen in windows, or in our browsers, is it possible that Safari or OSX is hijacking the POST request? Perhaps the webview needs to be created with an option turned on/off that we have missed. We have searched around but haven't been able to find anything, so if anyone has any insights it would be much appreciated.

Example Post request:

```
{
  "apptype": "Win",
  "calltype": "CC",
  "localTimestamp": "2014-12-10T22:37:35.499Z",
  "timezone": 7,
  "test": false,
  "version": "1.0",
  "deviceID": "Parallels-1A B0 48 1A 9F DE 43 4E 9D 99 D7 B3 10 69 4F 84",
  "machineID": "19b1bde9fd7ee2efc5d15bad37101229e9d3bc11d9ac9500bffc04c0e4e638fe",
  "model": "Parallels Virtual Platform",
  "userID": "739e94e70db1ed4372a8744f52dd5f3d",
  "country": "US",
  "language": "en-US",
  "contentID": "",
  "prod": "DEM1",
  "platformversion": "6.3.9600",
  "options": {
    "programArguments": {
      "contentURL": "http://www.google.com"
    },
    "launchSource": "manual",
    "visible": true
  }
}
```

Example response:

```
{
  "messageID": "1",
  "instructioncode": "displayContent",
  "contentID": "5",
  "date": "2014-12-10 15:37:36",
  "sessionID": "",
  "expirationdate": "2199-12-31 23:59:59",
  "contentURL": "http://www.google2.com",
  "options": {
    "remindMinutes": "4320"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142562/loading-a-webpage-through-uiwebview-with-post-parameters#answer-1143020 ?

Comment: no because the request isn't being assembled in the application. it's the server trying to make it directly to the other server, it's just getting changed in the process.

Comment: we loaded up a variety of other websites in the webview of the application and posts are never successful. it appears we have eliminated the api's as the problem entirely and it's just a webview/osx app issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never answered this after I figured it out so here it is:

the webview was created with this

```
- (NSURLRequest *)webView:(WebView *)sender
                                        resource:(id)identifier
                                        willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                        redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
                                        fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource
{
    // Replace the request with one that ignores the cache
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[request URL]
                                                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                    timeoutInterval:[request timeoutInterval]];
    return request;
}
```

the purpose of which was to make sure that the webview was never cached. it succeeded at that! but it also hijacked each request and turned the POST into a GET. the solution was just to comment it out and handle caching stuff on the server side rather then in the app.

```
- (NSURLRequest *)webView:(WebView *)sender
                                        resource:(id)identifier
                                        willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                        redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
                                        fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource
{
    // Replace the request with one that ignores the cache
    //request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[request URL]
                                                    //cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                    //timeoutInterval:[request timeoutInterval]];
    return request;
}
```