# WKWebView POST request

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I want to open a URL with `WKWebView` by passing some parameters along in the URL as a post request. But i am unable to do it. Please help.

Comment: "by passing some parameters along in the URL as a post request" POST parameters don't go in the URL. Please clarify.

Comment: Not actually a duplicate but this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26253133/653513

Comment: i meant something like https://example.com?email=krkapil@gmail.com&pass=password

Comment: i tried that example but its not working

Comment: @KapilRathore The example you shown was a GET request example. As @codran stated, POST parameters don't go in the URL. If you need to send POST, via `WKWebView`, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1143020/1492173) might help you.

Comment: @EugeneDubinin. That answer uses UIWebView, not WKWebView.

Comment: @MikeTaverne it does not matter in this case - `WKWebView` has similar method: `- (nullable WKNavigation *)loadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request` where the `NSMutableURLRequest` from aforementioned answer could be submitted to.

Comment: @EugeneDubinin Yes, it does matter. The answer you referred to sets HTTPBody which unfortunately does not work for WKWebView due to this bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=145410

Comment: @MikeTaverne that actually change everything related to the subject! The discussion on the bug gives some workaround with JavaScript. I did't  double-check it myself, though. Meanwhile, from discussion it wasn't clear to me whether or not someone's gonna fix it any time soon.

Comment: This will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253133/cant-set-headers-on-my-wkwebview-post-request/44951545#44951545

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't set headers on my WKWebView POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253133/cant-set-headers-on-my-wkwebview-post-request)

Answer (score 1):

```
var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(new NSString(paymentwebview.url))); //Your Url
request.HttpMethod = "POST";
request.Body = NSData.FromString(paymentwebview.data); //Data for POST
request["Content-Length"] = request.Body.Length.ToString();
request["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8";
LoadRequest(request);
```

Answer (score -2):

Had a similar problem. What worked for me was passing the parameters as cookies.

Code example:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
NSString *params = @"param1=value1;param2=value2;";
[request addValue:params forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't work for WKWebView - only for UIWebView.