# How do you log in to a website from an iOS Webview?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I'm working on an iOS app for my school that will allow the user to access school documents like schedules, calendars, and grade/tuition sites. I've been doing research on how to save credentials for some of the sites that require logins, and my ultimate goal is not only save credentials, but automatically log in the user to the websites when the webview is loaded as well. So far my code looks like this:

```
#import "PJP Webview.h"

@implementation PJP_Webview

@synthesize webView, loginView, username, password, body, urlToLink,usernameField,passwordField, firstTime, loginNeeded, callerCell;

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    loginView.hidden = true;

    if (firstTime && loginNeeded) {
        loginView.hidden = false;

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:loginView];
    }
    else {
        loginView.hidden = true;
        [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webView];

        if (loginNeeded) {
            NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSString *usernameSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@username", self.callerCell];
            self.username = [userDefaults objectForKey:usernameSave];
            NSString *passwordSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@password", self.callerCell];
            self.password = [userDefaults objectForKey:passwordSave];

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlToLink];
            NSString *bodyForUse = [NSString stringWithFormat: body, username, password];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
            [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
            [request setHTTPBody: [bodyForUse dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [webView loadRequest: request];
        }
        else {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlToLink];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [webView loadRequest:request];
        }
    }

}

- (IBAction)acceptInput:(id)sender {
    self.username = usernameField.text;
    self.password = passwordField.text;

    loginView.hidden = true;
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webView];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *usernameSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@username", self.callerCell];
    [userDefaults setObject:username forKey:usernameSave];

    NSString *passwordSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@password", self.callerCell];
     [userDefaults setObject:password forKey:passwordSave];

    [userDefaults synchronize];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlToLink];
    NSString *bodyForUse = [NSString stringWithFormat: body, username, password];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: [bodyForUse dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [webView loadRequest: request];
}
@end
```

I modeled some of my code after another stack overflow article found here [Loading a webpage through UIWebView with POST parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142562/loading-a-webpage-through-uiwebview-with-post-parameters)

An example of one of the websites I am trying to integrate is https://adphila.gradeconnect.com/front/slogin.php

So far my code has not been successful at logging me into the website and taking me to the next page, so I'm not sure if maybe the body I am using for the parameters is wrong, if my code is faulty, or some other issue is present. Also, if you have any suggestions for how to make my previous code more efficient I welcome that too!

Edit: The school also uses gmail for student emails, so is it possible to embed a uiwebview of email content as well? I know Google has their own APIs but I have never used non-Apple libraries before.

Edit 2:

```
#import "PJP Webview.h"

@implementation PJP_Webview

@synthesize webViewCurrent, loginView, username, password, bodyUsername, bodyPassword, urlToLink,usernameField,passwordField, firstTime, loginNeeded, callerCell, bodyButton;

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webViewCurrent setDelegate:self];

    loginView.hidden = true;

    if (firstTime && loginNeeded) {
        loginView.hidden = false;

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:loginView];
    }
    else {
        loginView.hidden = true;

        if (loginNeeded) {
            NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSString *usernameSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@username", self.callerCell];
            self.username = [userDefaults objectForKey:usernameSave];
            NSString *passwordSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@password", self.callerCell];
            self.password = [userDefaults objectForKey:passwordSave];

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlToLink];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [webViewCurrent loadRequest:request];
        }
        else {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlToLink];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [webViewCurrent loadRequest:request];
        }
        [self.view addSubview:self.webViewCurrent];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webViewCurrent];
    }
}

- (IBAction)acceptInput:(id)sender {
    self.username = usernameField.text;
    self.password = passwordField.text;

    loginView.hidden = true;

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *usernameSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@username", self.callerCell];
    [userDefaults setObject:username forKey:usernameSave];

    NSString *passwordSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@password", self.callerCell];
     [userDefaults setObject:password forKey:passwordSave];

    [userDefaults synchronize];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlToLink];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webViewCurrent loadRequest:request];

    [self.view addSubview:self.webViewCurrent];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webViewCurrent];
}

-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *fillData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('%@').value = '%@';document.getElementById('%@').value = '%@';", bodyUsername, username, bodyPassword, password];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:fillData];

    NSString *buttonData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('%@').click()", bodyButton];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:buttonData];
}

@end
```

There is a new error though, void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

For the website I am using, the bodyUsername is lusername, the bodyPassword lpassword, and the bodyButton login. The page loads but is not executing the javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by Autopopulating the username and password field of that webpage. First get the name of the username and password field from the webpage. right click on the webpage.
Click on inspect element and then You van easily find it.
Then write the WebView Delegate Method.

```
//  ViewController.m
//  WebDemo
//
//  Created by Nilesh on 7/31/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Nilesh. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *urlToLink = @"https://adphila.gradeconnect.com/front/slogin.php";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlToLink];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSString* userId   =  @"userName" ;//Your userName
    NSString* password =   @"password";// Your Password


    NSString*  jScriptString1 = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"document.forms[0]['lusername'].value='%@'", userId];

    NSString*  jScriptString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.forms[0]['lpassword'].value='%@'", password];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jScriptString1];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jScriptString2];

    NSString *jsStat = @"document.forms[0]['login'].click()";

   [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsStat];


}
@end
```

Comment: I updated my code to include this. Now I have the error: void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Comment: That error is due to JavaScript code.. Actually JavaScript execution time is fixed to 10 seconds for each entry. If your code executes more than 10 seconds then webview stops executing the script... That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: Ok, what can I do to correct this error and have the code run successfully?

Comment: I have update the answer .. Now try it.. Try for Login Button Action.. The fields are populating . I have checked it.. And get back if their is any problem.