# Pass Token Through URL into Webview IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, webview

Hello I am using webview to display my contents on my app. I successfully registered with firebase. Now I want to pass the registration token through URL to store into DB for custom notification.

**appdelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let token = deviceToken.map {String (format: "%02.2hhx", $0)}.joined()
    print(token)
}
```

**Firebase**

```
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    //Saving fcmToken to pass to the url
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    preferences.setValue(fcmToken, forKey: "token")
    preferences.synchronize()


    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
```

and this is for **viewcontroller.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Retrieving the fcmToken
    let prefs = UserDefaults.standard
    let token = prefs.string(forKey: "token")
    //?token= \(token as Optional)&device=ios
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://instaglamexpress.com/app/customer/?device=ios&token=\(String(describing: token))")!))
}
```

I am unable to send Token into URL..

please suggest the solution.

Comment: You can send it this way : https://stackoverflow.com/q/1142562/2323806

Comment: You don't need to use `synchronize `

Answer (score 0):

You need optional binding here with `if let` because `prefs.string(forKey: "token")` will return optional value.

Consider below code:

```
let prefs = UserDefaults.standard
if let token = prefs.string(forKey: "token") {
    //token is not optional anymore
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://instaglamexpress.com/app/customer/?device=ios&token=\(token))")!))  
}
```

Or you can use `guard let` which will do the same job.

Comment: I am getting blank screen now... when I am trying to run into simulator and into real device as well...

Comment: Have you checked that url in browser?

Comment: [C1.1:2][0x7fd37a80fa30] get output frames failed, state 8196... I m getting this into the info bar...

Comment: can you print `"https://instaglamexpress.com/app/customer/?device=ios&token=\(token))"` and share the result?

Comment: Where and how to print...?? I am getting "get output frame failed, state 8196" in all output..

Comment: let prefs = UserDefaults.standard
        //var token : String!
        let token = prefs.string(forKey: "token")
        //?token= \(token as Optional)&device=ios
        print("Token accessed : \(String(describing: token))")
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://instaglamexpress.com/app/customer/?device=ios&token=\(String(describing: token))")!))
        
    }

when I am using this code then app loading fine but not getting token. it is showing nil on my page..

Comment: That means you are not saving it correct. So check when you are saving it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi tested your code and modified and it works

modification of the last part

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Retrieving the fcmToken
    let prefs = UserDefaults.standard
    let token = prefs.string(forKey: "token") ?? ""

    webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://instaglamexpress.com/app/customer/?device=ios&token="+token)!))
}
```

It's simply a string and Xcode proposes to Coalescing

`let token = prefs.string(forKey: "token") ?? ""`

and simply use token as regular variable without fancy stuff `"url"+token` and voila

;)

Note: when you hit play and xcode compiles it, it's empty (but only the first time) you quit the app and re-open normally and it's all ok.